# How to add author's user role as CSS class to comments?

Tags: theming

Snippet from Bartik's comment.html.twig ( https://pastebin.com/D70cyHNp ):

```
{{ user_picture }}
    <p class="comment__author">{{ author }}</p>
    <p class="comment__time">{{ created }}</p>
```

I want to highlight comments by administrators with CSS so how can I say "if the comment author has the role administrator, add the class "comment_author_is_administrator" to the author variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done pretty easily by preprocessing your comments.

But first of all, very important: don't edit any of Bartik's files (or any core files in general). Create a [sub-theme](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/creating-a-drupal-8-sub-theme-or-sub-theme-of-sub-theme), copy the `comment.html.twig` to your sub-theme's `templates` directory and edit that file.

Second, depending on your CSS setup `comment_author_is_administrator` doesn't seem like a legit CSS class. Normally, underscores are not allowed to be used that way. And maybe you can make it a little bit shorter. Maybe just `author-administrator`.

Finally, simply place the following snippet in you sub-theme's `*.theme` file and replace `MYTHEME` with your actual theme name.

```
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_comment.
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_comment(&$variables) {

  // Get the comment.
  $comment = $variables['comment'];

  // Get its owner.
  $owner = $comment->getOwner();

  // Check for administrator role.
  if ($owner->hasRole('administrator')) {

    // Append CSS class.
    $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'author-administrator';
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you could simply append each comment's author role as CSS class like following.

```
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_page.
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_comment(&$variables) {

  $comment = $variables['comment'];
  $owner = $comment->getOwner();
  $roles = $owner->getRoles();

  // Let's pop the roles array to only
  // get the last (highest) role of all.
  $role = array_pop($roles)

  $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'author-' . $role;
}
```